# My link is not recognized by its parent <div>. why?

Tags: css

I have a `<a>` in a `<div>` but the `<div>` doesn't recongize the `<a>` and adjust and increase its height to accomodate the link.

Check it out my html/css here: http://jsfiddle.net/RjfVN/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `section-link` class has `float: left;`
You need to clear the float. To do this you can add a div directly after the closing `</a>` like:

```
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

**Or**

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And add `.clearfix{ clear: both; }` to your css so you can reuse it.

Comment: Thanks. Your fix works. How does the float:left in section-link prevents the parent <div> from calculating its height as expected?

Comment: @burnt1ce floating elements "break out" of the layout. They don't take up any space in the layout of get considered by elements around them. The `clear` style in css allows you to clear the float so the element you have the `clear` style on will go below the float instead of ignoring it: http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_clear.cfm Adding an empty div like this with clear, makes their be layout below your `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

Put overflow:auto to your #main.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, your link is using `float:left`. There are a few ways to fix it.

1. Have something after the link (like `#footer` for instance) `clear: left` (or `both`).
2. Float the `#main` container div as well, or give it `position: absolute`
3. Add `overflow: auto` to the `#main` container div.

However, in cases 2 & 3 you will need to set the width of the container as well, since it won't have the initial 100% width that it's using. Also, in Internet explorer, setting the width is actually required for the overflow to have any effect because it forces the container to `hasLayout`.